# Does Google Drive no longer allow JavaScript file referencing from other website?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I just noticed that all my javascript files hosted on Google Drive no longer work, which previously [officially allowed by Google](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en). All variables and function calls become undefined (as indicated in Chrome console), but all the while, they were working fine. Below is my link reference:

```
<script charset='utf-8' src='https://googledrive.com/host/0B_kAR1YCVojTQnlmMXA0cWhfNGM' type='text/javascript'/>
```

The access permission had been set to public all the time and it is still remain as public. In my HTML file, I call the function as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">setDefaultShow(13, 13);</script>
```

This had been working fine until recently. May I know what else could it be wrong? Could it be due to that, Google Drive no longer allows javascript file referencing from other website? If the answer is 'Yes', any other alternative to host my javascript files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "alternative to host my javascript" - Where do you host your HTML files?

Comment: see https://plus.google.com/108192375095500160194/posts/i8hUFRonsFn

Comment: Thanks Dan! At least I'm not alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got off the phone with Google and they're aware of the problem.  They still allow the hosting of javascript files on GoogleDrive, it's just not working for some people and hasn't been for last day and a half.  In the meantime (or probably from now on) I'm using Amazon's Simple Storage Service: http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Looks like an answer to me!

Answer (score 5):

Try using the direct link generator here https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/

Step 1: Go to Google Drive and right click the file that you want to share.
Now click on "Share...".

Step 2: On the window that comes up, click "Get shareable link".

Step 3: Make sure the dropdown is set to one of the "Anyone with the link..."
or "Anyone on the internet..." options, then click "Copy link".

Step 4: Now just paste that link into the text box above and create your direct link. Enjoy!

Comment: Cool! But I have migrated all my files to Firebase. Thanks anyway! ^^

Answer (score 1):

we managed to work around this issue
it seems related with the MIME type, the loading is failing for JS file with application/x-javascript as mime type (they were fine before)
JS file with mime type text/plain are loading fine.

you can try this code to identify the files with mime problem withing an specific folder

```
var fid = "your-folder-id-here";
function myFunction() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fid);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName() + " - " + file.getMimeType());
  }
}
```

Comment: Some people suggested to rename the file extension to **.txt**. It seems like as long as you won't reference it as JS, Google Drive will not making any noise about it. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Google has fixed this issue as of 2/9/2015.  The steps below are no longer required and if used will result in an unexpected MIME type console warning.  However, I'm leaving my original response in case the issue resurfaces.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I was able to fix the issue with this method:

1. **gDrive:**  download all *.js files to your local drive
2. **gDrive:**  delete all *.js files
3. **local drive:** batch rename all the *.js files to *.txt
4. **local drive:**  upload all *.txt files to gDrive
5. **local drive:**  batch rename all the *.txt files to *.js (i.e. revert step 3)
6. **gDrive:**  individually rename all *.txt files to *.js (major pain)

This method ensures that the MIME type of the file on gDrive is text/plain because you're uploading files with the .txt extension.  When you rename the files to .js on gDrive, the MIME type is preserved.